# html form data using php to insert it to mysql table and post table data. Table dont receive input or output data

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, forms

sorry for all the code but i am having problem with getting the form data into my table and output the table content under the submit button on the form. I would appreciate all the help i could get, i been searching for problems now for 5 whole days. I have created a comment from MySQL Query so i know the anmeldelserdisplay.php does not work.

Brief explanation of what i want to happen:

Check if filled correct when submit, form redirects to anmeldelserprocess.php sending email to specified email.

store form data in MySQL comment table in nesentreprenor database when submit with same button.

Post comment on website with stored data from database table.

Redirect to thank you page which redirect back to anmeldelser.php which is where the comments are.

All this from same "Send" button.

The anmeldelservalidation.js / anmeldelsersettings.php / takk.htm i assume works but i post it for a full view, hope this is not as much trouble for you as for me. Thank you for any help i get.

MySQL table

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Full_Name` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
`Email_Adress` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
`Your_Message` text,
`timestamp` timestamp(6) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

anmeldelser.html

```
<?php include("./anmeldelsermanage.php"); ?>
<form name="anmeldelser" id="post" method="post" action="anmeldelserprocess.php" onsubmit="return validate.check(this)">
<table width="400px" class="anmeldelser">
<tr>
 <td colspan="2">
 <div class="anmeldelserheader">Felt markert med <span class="required_star"> * </span> er obligatorisk.</div>
 <br />
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="Full_Name" class="required"><span class="required_star"> * </span>Ditt Navn</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input type="text" style="font-size:120%; font-family:arial;" name="Full_Name" id="Full_Name" maxlength="30" size="30" style="width:230px">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="Email_Address" class="required"><span class="required_star"> * </span>Din Email Addresse</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input type="text" style="font-size:120%; font-family:arial;" name="Email_Address" id="Email_Address" maxlength="100" size="30" style="width:230px">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="Your_Message" class="required"><span class="required_star"> * </span>Din Kommentar</label><br />
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea style="width:400px; height:160px; font-size:120%; font-family:arial;" name="Your_Message" id="Your_Message" maxlength="3000"></textarea>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center" >
  <br />
  <div class="antispammessage">
  <br />
      <div class="antispamquestion">
       <span class="required_star"> * </span>
       Bruk nummere. Hva er 10 + 15 + 25? &nbsp; 
       <input type="text" name="AntiSpam" id="AntiSpam" maxlength="100" style="width:30px">
      </div>
   <br />
  </div>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center" >
 <br />
  <input type='hidden' />
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" class="button" value=" Send ">
  <br /><br />

 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<br />
<hr style="width: 1105px;" />
<br />
<br />
<?php include("./anmeldelserdisplay.php"); ?>
```

anmeldelsermanage.php

```
<?php
If(isset($_POST)){
$con = mysql_connect("","","");

  if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("nesentreprenor", $con);

$users_name = $_POST["Full_Name"];
$users_email = $_POST["Email_Address"];
$users_comment = $_POST["Your_Message"];

$users_name = mysql_real_escape_string($users_name);
$users_email = mysql_real_escape_string($users_email);
$users_comment = mysql_real_escape_string($users_comment);

$query = "
INSERT INTO `nesentreprenor`.`comments` (`Full_Name`, `Email_Address`, Your_Message`, `timestamp`)`
VALUES ('$users_name', '$users_email', '$users_comment', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";`

mysql_query($query);

echo "<h2>manage</h2>";

mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

anmeldelserdisplay.php

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("","","");

if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("nesentreprenor", $con);

$query = "SELECT id, Full_Name, Email_Address, Your_Message, timestamp FROM comments";
$result = $con->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {echo "<br> id: ". $row["id"]. " - Name: ". $row["Full_Name"]. " " . $row["Email_Address"] . "<br>";}
} else {echo "0 results";}

$comments = mysql_query($query);

echo "<h1>User Comments</h1>";

while($row = mysql_fetch-array($comments, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$name = $row['Full_Name'];
$email = $row['Email_Address'];
$comment = $row['Your_Message'];
$timestamp = $row['timestamp'];

$name = htmlspecialchars($row['name'],ENT_QUOTES);
$email = htmlspecialchars($row['email'],ENT_QUOTES);
$comment = htmlspecialchars($row['comment'],ENT_QUOTES);

echo "  <div style='margin:30px 0px;'>
  Name: $name<br />
  Email: $email<br />
  Comment: $comment<br />
  Timestamp: $timestamp
</div>
";
}

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

anmeldelserprocess.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Email_Address'])) {

include 'anmeldelsersettings.php';

function died($error) {
    echo "Beklager, det er (flere) feil med dokumentet du prøvde å sende. ";
    echo "Filene kan finnes under.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Gå tilbake å fiks disse feilene.<br /><br />";
    die();
}
if(!isset($_POST['Full_Name']) ||
!isset($_POST['Email_Address']) ||
!isset($_POST['Your_Message']) || 
!isset($_POST['AntiSpam'])      
) {died('Beklager, det er feil med dokumentet du prøvde å sende.');
}

$full_name = $_POST['Full_Name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['Email_Address']; // required
$comments = $_POST['Your_Message']; // required
$antispam = $_POST['AntiSpam']; // required

$error_message = "";

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)==0) {
$error_message .= 'E-post feltet er ikke korrekt!<br />';
}
if(strlen($full_name) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'Navne feltet er ikke korrekt!<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'Kommentar feltet må fylles ut!<br />';
}

if($antispam <> $antispam_answer) {
$error_message .= 'Validerings koden din stemmer ikke!<br />';
}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$email_message = "Du har fått en kommentar på www.\r\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "".clean_string($full_name)." har kommentert på nettsiden din! http://xn--nes-entreprenr-2qb.no/anmeldelser.html\r\n";
$email_message .= "Navn: ".clean_string($full_name)."\r\n";
$email_message .= "Fra: ".clean_string($email_from)."\r\n";
$email_message .= "Kommentar: ".clean_string($comments)."\r\n";
$email_message .= "Dato: ".clean_string($date)."\r\n";

$headers = 'Fra: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Til: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>
<script>location.replace('<?php echo $takk;?>')</script>
<?php
}
die();
?>
```

anmeldelsersettings.php

```
<?php
$email_to = "";
$email_subject = "";
$takk = "./takk/takk.htm";
$antispam_answer = "50";
?>
```

anmeldelservalidation.js

```
function has_id(id){try{var tmp=document.getElementById(id).value;}catch(e){return false;}
return true;}
function has_name(nm){try{var tmp=cfrm.nm.type;}catch(e){return false;}
return true;}
function $$(id){if(!has_id(id)&&!has_name(id)){alert("Field "+id+" does not exist!\n Form validation configuration error.");return false;}
if(has_id(id)){return document.getElementById(id).value;}else{return;}}
function $val(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
function trim(id){$val(id).value=$val(id).value.replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,'');}
var required={field:[],add:function(name,type,mess){this.field[this.field.length]=[name,type,mess];},out:function(){return this.field;},clear:function(){this.field=[];}};var validate={check:function(cform){var error_message='Vennligst fiks disse feilene:\n\n';var mess_part='';var to_focus='';var tmp=true;for(var i=0;i<required.field.length;i++){if(this.checkit(required.field[i][0],required.field[i][1],cform)){}else{error_message=error_message+required.field[i][2]+' må være fylt ut!\n';if(has_id(required.field[i][0])&&to_focus.length===0){to_focus=required.field[i][0];}
tmp=false;}}
if(!tmp){alert(error_message);}
if(to_focus.length>0){document.getElementById(to_focus).focus();}
return tmp;},checkit:function(cvalue,ctype,cform){if(ctype=="NOT_EMPTY"){if(this.trim($$(cvalue)).length<1){return false;}else{return true;}}else if(ctype=="EMAIL"){exp=/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;if($$(cvalue).match(exp)==null){return false;}else{return true;}}},trim:function(s){if(s.length>0){return s.replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,'');}else{return s;}}};
```

takk.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//NB" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="nb" xml:lang="nb">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=http://nes-entreprenør.no/anmeldelser.html">
</head>
<body>

<center><h1>Tusen takk</h1></center>
<center><p><b>Nes-Entreprenør har fått din melding.</b></p></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That `clean_string` function is uselessly weak if you're looking for just a handful of values.

Comment: You're also using `mysqli` which is fine, but `mysql_query` too which is **super bad**, especially not escaping things properly.

Comment: think the reason why you don't get feedback is that not many people want to read through all your code, nor want to copy everything to their own server for testing. What steps did you take to find the problem yourself? You can use var_dump() and exit() to check whats going on in your code and where it stops to work. Before you do that, change `mysql_fetch-array` to `mysql_fetch_array` in your anmeldserdisplay.php. Good Luck!